# how to handle pygame VideoExpose event

Tags: python, pygame, event-handling

I was experimenting with `pygame` and noticed it raised a `VideoExpose` event when I press alt+tab and the window is fullscreen. when I switch press alt+tab again, everything on the screen is moved to the bottom left.
I know that this is supposed to mean that 'portions of the window must be redrawn', but how am I supposed to redraw them and what why does `pygame` even have this event in the first place?

Comment: Which version of pygame are you using? There was recently a [bug fix](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2161) included in `2.0.0.dev16` that affects spurious `VIDEOEXPOSE` events.

Comment: I have pygame 1.9.6, but I wouldn't care if I updated the version of pygame.

Comment: You can try out the latest prerelease of pygame using `pip install pygame --pre`. For further assistance with your specific issue, you'll need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing a program to use the windowing Event Model, the windowing environment sends the program events to notify it of environmental changes - window resize, mouse move, need to re-paint, etc.

*Not handling these events will cause your application to be considered "non responsive" by the environment.  Here on SO, there's about one question a week with PyGame and exactly this issue.*

When working with PyGame re-drawing event handling may seem superfluous as the majority of PyGame games redraw the entire screen every frame, e.g.: 60 FPS.  But if unnecessary, this method is a complete waste of resources (CPU-time, electricity, etc.) It *is* quite simple though, so good for beginners.

Say you were writing a card game like [Solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solitaire)... the screen updates *only* when interacting with the user.  In terms of CPU, it's doing nothing 99.9% of the time while the user contemplates their next move.  In this case, the program could be written to only re-draw the screen when necessary.  *When* is it necessary?  When the player gives input, or the program receives a `pygame.VIDEOEXPOSE` event from the widowing environment.

If your program is redrawing the window constantly, you can simply ignore the message.  If not, when receiving the message call whatever block of code is normally used to render the window.  The expose message may come with the region of the screen that needs to be re-drawn, in this case a really good application would only update that section of the display.